# Comparing Current Date and Time Against a File

Tags: date, unix, time, comparison

I am looking to compare the last updated date and time of a file against the current date.

To date the date/time of the file I am splitting up the time and date tag like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*.dat -printf "%Tm,%Td,%TH,%TM\n"
```

And I am looking to match this against the current date:

```
date '+%m,%d,%H,%M'
```

Both are in the same format - `DD MM HH MM` - and I would like to compare if the time is more than two minutes out.

What would be my best option for coding this - can I use the values I have obtained?

Or even - would there be an easier method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an easier way.

You can use

```
find -mmin -2
```

for finding all the entries which have been changed less than two minutes ago.

Or, of course, use

```
find -mmin +2
```

to find the entries which are older than two minutes (have been changed more than two minutes ago).

Comment: That is fantastic - much appreciated.  If I could upvote more I would.

Comment: It's more or less just reading the man page (or having it read years ago and remembering what's written there).  I think one upvote is enough for that ;-)  Anyway, thank you :)